# How come memory leaks happen on IOS when ARC is used?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

In my IOS app, I used automatic reference counting mechanism, but I still get bad memory access errors and bunch of memory leaks? Can someone inform me on the topic?

Comment: It's probably because you have retain cycles in your code and/or are using strong references when you should use weak instead.  I don't think you've provided enough detail for us to help you.

Comment: Maybe some of the ARC constraints/expectations are violated? Either that or ARC is flawed - but assuming that it can avoid memory leaks/issues for correctly written code - then the problem is in the *particular* usage of such. And, this question shows no [minimal] test case of such problematic/suspected code ..

Comment: I got added to the project late and I am new to IOS development. I just want to know what is the best practice in terms of handling memory?

Comment: Take a look at Apple's Transitioning to ARC Release Notes for a general description. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: you won't get bad memory access errors due to retain cycles. are you using any `CoreFoundation`/`CoreGraphics` functions? Incorrect usage of `__bridge` cast will also cause memory problems.

Comment: Because no one really understands ARC.

Comment: Yes we use CoreFoundation/CoreGraphics

Comment: Could you give some examples of areas in your code where you are having memory access errors? Code samples or at least the error message would be helpful.